# Asp.net Mvc2 Ajax ImageActionLink Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax, actionlink

I'm fairly new to Mvc and ran into a problem try to use an Image as an Ajax Action link. I found a helper that I believe was posted by Stephen Walther...

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace Helpers
{
    public static class ImageActionLinkHelper
    {

        public static string ImageActionLink(this AjaxHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText, string actionName, object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
        {
            var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
            builder.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
            builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
            var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName, routeValues, ajaxOptions);
            return link.Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        }

    }
}
```

However the "Replace" method does not exist in the version I'm using. (maybe an Mvc2 issue since I believe his contact manager app was an MVC1 app??) A quick search through the docs and I found the "Replace" method as obsolete and it was suggesed to use "MvcHtmlString.Create()" I tried a number of combinations in this helper using that method and I could not get the link to render with an image.  I would either get a link pointing to the correct action/controller and the img tag as plain text OR vice versa a correctly rendered img with the link as plain text.

Just as a sidenote on almost all the combos I tried, I was returning a type MvcHtmlString instead of the standard string listed in this particular helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably from when `MvcHtmlString` didn't exist yet. You should be able to make this work with `Replace()` method tho, just need to get the actual string it was supposed to work with in the first place:

```
var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName, routeValues, ajaxOptions).ToString();
return link.Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
```

Comment: When I add the helper, the project wont build because it says Replace() method doesnt exist.

Comment: Yes that's what I said. You have to call `ToString()` on the result you get from `helper.ActionLink()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didnt see the ToString() at the end of your first line, definitely works now! 
Thanks!

Comment: Sweet. That fixed my problem going from MVC1 to MVC2. :)